# Displaying value in richTextBox doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I tried displaying the value of `richTextBox17`, but no matter what I do, the `displayed value stays at 2000`. Is there anything, I missed?

```
if (richTextBox17.Text == "")
{
  richTextBox17.Text = "2000";
}

// calculate delay overall
int delayOverall = Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox9.Text) + 
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox10.Text) + 
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox11.Text) +
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox12.Text) + 
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox13.Text) + 
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox14.Text) +
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox15.Text) + 
                   Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox16.Text);

//if interval > delay overall -> interval = delay overall
if (Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox17.Text) > delayOverall)
{
  richTextBox17.Text = Convert.ToString(delayOverall);
}

// activate timer1 after 3000 ms and set interval
Thread.Sleep(3000);
timer1.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(richTextBox17.Text);
timer1.Start();
```

Comment: Maybe `delayOverall` is greater than 2000?  You can debug this to see what it's doing.

Comment: This code is missing context. When is this code called? Do you have to parse values set in the UI without validation every time this code is called (using Controls that don't have meaningful names)? How is the Timer related to this? I.e., why do you Thread.Sleep() there?

Comment: a) Do use the debugger for this kind of issue before coming here! b) You really shouldn't directly change the rtf.Text property or else you will lose all formatting!